# Windows 7 Laptop loads slowly then freezes

Tags: windows-7, boot, performance, freeze

This started happening earlier today. I booted up my laptop and it takes forever to load into Windows 7. I then booted it into Safe Mode, ran Malwarebytes and it found some malware that I got rid of but it still took forever to load up. I waited until it finally loaded into Windows and used msconfig to see what programs boot up at start up and got rid of some of the unnecessary startup programs. After doing that, I tried to get out of msconfig, and the computer froze. It is slow and froze while in Safe Mode as well. Is this a hard drive issue or perhaps I should try chkdsk? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: yes, this could be a Hard drive issue. Backup all data and run a HDD diag tool from the manufacture of the HDD.

Comment: D/l SeaTools HD diag and it failed the test, so I think I found my answer.

Comment: yeah, the HDD is damaged. Replace it.